# Pulling "All but X" in a select statement, testing multiple fields at once

Tags: sql

So after doing a very large select statement, I wanted to check if there was a slick way to pull all the fields paired on multiple tables into a report while testing a large set of null fields to have empty records removed. Say for example I have table a paired to table b paired to table c. I want almost all the records except for a.something, b.somthing, and a couple c.somethings.

I also want to make sure if all the fields in c are empty, exclude the record. (Well... all but the index)

Is there a good way to do this? I ended up building a largish report field by field but it was A: Mostly tedious and B: Would not scale if I ever ran into a bigger project.

```
SELECT * <except for c.4, c.5. c.6, a.3, a.4, b.2>
    FROM a,b,c
        LEFT JOIN b ON a.indexA = b.indexA
        LEFT JOIN c ON b.indexB = c.indexB
            WHERE a.1 is not null
            AND b.1 is not null
            and c.1 is not null
            and c.2 is not null
            and c.3 is not null
            and a.2 is > 0
            and b.2 = 'Test'
```

Feel free not to use my example.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do multiple join conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.indexA = b.indexA 
        and b.1 is not null
        and b.2 = 'Test'
    LEFT JOIN c ON b.indexB = c.indexB 
        and c.1 is not null
        and c.2 is not null
        and c.3 is not null
    WHERE a.1 is not null
        and a.2 is > 0
```

Also, I'm pretty sure when specifying the `left join` syntax as you have, listing all of the tables after the `FROM` is not necessary.

I'm not sure if this will change the performance at all however.